# Update a TextBlock with elapsed time causing an UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, silverlight, multithreading

I have a very simple StopWatch application in Silverlight.  I have the following private properties in my `MainPage` class: `_StopPressed` (bool), `_TimeStart`, `_Elapsed` (string).  I also have a "Start" and "Stop" button.

The "Start" button calls a method called `UpdateTime` that constantly updates `_ElapsedTime` until `_StopPressed` is true.  When I originally wrote it, `UpdateTime` would block the UI so I couldn't press the Stop button, so I updated my code to use `System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` with my `UpdateTime` method so that it updates `_Elapsed` on a background thread. That works great at updating the value.

However, if I try to set the `.Text` value of my `TextBlock` from within `UpdateTime()`, I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` that has to do with one thread accessing the data in another thread.

What do I need to do to avoid getting this exception and appropriately update the UI without blocking it?

Comment: try updating the text using dispatcher :

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                                       { .Text="Hello" });

Comment: @Malcolm that gets it to update the text one time, but then it freezes and blocks the UI.

Comment: take a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DispatcherTimer instead of a timer, works nearly exactly the same but is used for updating UI elements.